# how to increase counter from 1, 2, to 3, with one click?

Tags: javascript

i have some code but i am doing something wrong, how can i increment the value smoothly to 3? At the end when the counter is 3 I should see the initial value "click me: 0"

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-counter').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const btn = e.target;
  let curr = (+btn.dataset.clicks)
  btn.dataset.clicks = ++curr % 4;

  btn.innerHTML = 'click me: ' + btn.dataset.clicks;
});
```

```css
.btn-counter {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-counter" id="clicks" data-clicks="0">clikc me: 0</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "smoothly"? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to see how the value changes on the screen starting from 1, 2, 3, and then return to the initial text "click me 0"

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You need to define your count-variables outside of the click-method. It gets reseted in your example.

Comment: @ALex You want that on single click or multiple clicks?

Comment: So are you actually asking how to "animate" through the numbers as they count up? Showing each one for X amount of time, before they progress without any user input. (And then reset at the end)

Comment: Please add all such clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do - note the addition of `data-clicks="0"` on the element itself.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-counter').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const btn = e.target;
  let curr = (+btn.dataset.clicks)
  btn.dataset.clicks = ++curr % 4;

  btn.innerHTML = 'click me: ' + btn.dataset.clicks;
});
```

```css
.btn-counter {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-counter" id="clicks" data-clicks="0">click me: 0</div>
```

---

Turns out thats not what you were after, but instead to animate the count and return to 0.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-counter').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let curr = 0;
  const btn = e.target;
  const delay = 1000;
  
  const increment = () => {
    curr++;
    btn.innerHTML = curr;
    if(curr <4)
      setTimeout(increment,delay);
    else {
      curr = 0
      btn.innerHTML = "click me: 0"
    }
  }
  
  setTimeout(increment,delay);
  
});
```

```css
.btn-counter {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-counter" id="clicks">click me: 0</div>
```

Comment: is it possible in js to make the counter go from 1, 2, 3 with one click? i have to display them at X time ?

Comment: @ALex is the update more what you were after?

Comment: this is what I need, thanks